# Send http post request with unicoded data using python requests

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests

I want to send a post request to REST api, but with all my characters unicode encoded, for example the string `test` i want to send as `\u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074`. Whatever i try, the string ends up as `\\u0074\\u0065\\u0073\\u0074`. I can easily modify the request in for example Burp, and remove the double backslashes, to make it work.

So the raw bytes sent to the webserver is `\x5c\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x34\x5c\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x36\x35\x5c\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x33\x5c\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x34`

While what i want is:
`\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x34\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x36\x35\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x33\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x34`

One of the things I've tried is this:

```
import requests

s = 'test'
data = ''
for c in s:
    data +=  "\\u00"+hex(ord(c))[2:].lower()
print(data)
json =  {"user":data}
res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/api/getusers', json=json)
print(res.text)
```

even if i set `data = '\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x34\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x36\x35\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x33\x5c\x75\x30\x30\x37\x34'` is still sends double back slahes (`\x5x\x5c`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. Tested with `https://httpbin.davecheney.com/post`, Python 3.7 and Requests 2.23.0:

```py
import requests, json

url = r"https://httpbin.davecheney.com/post"

data_raw_str = r"\u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074"

s = 'test'
data = ''
for c in s:
    data += '\\u00' + hex(ord(c))[2:].lower()
    #data += fr"\u{ord(c):04x}" # this works, too
    
json_dict = {'user': data}
r = requests.post(url, json=json_dict)
print(r)

data_returned = json.loads(r.json()['data'])['user']

print(data_raw_str)
print(data)
print(data_returned)
print(data_raw_str == data == data_returned)
print(requests.__version__)
```

Output:

```
<Response [200]>
\u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074
\u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074
\u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074
True
2.23.0
```

**Edit:**

According to [RFC 8259 - The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7) - 7. Strings:

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks, except for the characters that MUST be escaped: quotation mark, **reverse solidus**, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).

So backslashes will always be escaped with another backslash in JSON.

I believe manually removing the extra backslashes will cause the server's JSON decoder to unescape the unicode literals so your string will become plain old `test`.

Why does the request have to be JSON?

If you make this request, no additional backslashes are added:

`requests.post(url, data=data) # data is a str`

And if you make this request, the keys and values are `utf-8` encoded, and then url encoded (the single backslash is replaced with `%5C`):

`requests.post(url, data=json_dict)`

Comment: It seems to be working from the client side. But if you either intercept the request using a proxy, or look at the data in Wireshark, you can see that the data sent is with `\x5c\x5c`, or `\\` ascii.

I tested your example, and it yields the same result.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated my answer. Long story short, JSON strings cannot include an unescaped (single) backslash. Make a POST request that doesn't send JSON if you mustn't have unescaped backslashes.

Comment: the server only accepts json, but i guess i can create json as a string and send. Thanks for the in depth answer :)